# add-on with LIMITED auth cannot open sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-docs, google-apps-script-addon

I have a Google docs add-on which is programmed to open the sidebar as soon as the document is open. Of course this requires the add-on to be installed and enabled in the document.

I see that, since a week, the sidebar auto open feature, which is very useful in our use case, no longer works.

In StackDriver logs I see this report :

```
onOpen():  {authMode=LIMITED, source=Document, user=} 
publi-2.0.72-2017-11-27-18-57               [this is the publication version tag]
2017-11-27T18:02:50.126Z : show menu 
2017-11-27T18:02:50.180Z : show sidebar 
Error showing sidebar  Exception: You do not have permission to call showSidebar 
2017-11-27T18:02:50.283Z : end onOpen
```

So clearly, the add-on is in LIMITED mode and showSidebar() should succeed, according to the [addon authorization lifecyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle) (just look at the column LIMITED in the table).

**--> I suspect a bug or a new security limitation was introduced recently.**

For the record here is a code snippet :

```
/**
 * Basic setup. At the beginning:
 * 1. Add a "Add-ons" menu item.
 * 2. Display the doxMaster sidebar.
 */
function onOpen(e) {
    console.log("onOpen(): ",e)
    console.log(addonversion);
    doServerLog("show menu");
    showMenu();
    doServerLog("show sidebar");
    showSidebar();
    doServerLog("end onOpen");
}

/**
 * Creates the Add-ons menu at the google drive panel.
 */
function showMenu() {
    DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
        .addItem(translate("sidebarMenu"), showSidebar.name)
        .addItem(translate("joinFollowingParagraph"), insertJoinFollowingParaSymbol.name)
        .addItem(translate("importDocument"), importDocument.name)
        .addItem(translate("about"), about.name)
        .addToUi();

}

/**
 * Creates a doxMaster Add-on Sidebar.
 */
function showSidebar() {
    try {
        var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sidebar');
        var html = htmlTemplate.evaluate().setTitle(translate("appTitle"));
        DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Error showing sidebar ", e); // Add-on has not been enabled in this document
    }
}
```

Comment: @SandyGood Any Updates on this? Because, if you try to use some of third party templates from Google Docs Template Gallery (e.g. Pandadoc Templates in Sales category), this add-ons can start automatically.

Comment: @aaryan See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57503369/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday we've noticed exactly the same problem as you Yves.
However for us it occurs in a Google Sheets addon.

I've created an issue at Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69824548

Please star and comment so it gets picked up soon!

Comment: After some more test I see that even an add-on in which the sidebar.html file is reduced to a mere <p>Hello World</p> requests the new privilege "Display and run Third-party web content in prompts and sidebars inside Google Applications".
-> This is weird because there is no such content in the add-on.

Comment: The referred issue was merged with https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69238694 which is marked as "Won't Fix"

Answer (score 1):

From https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle

> Note: Add-ons can't open sidebars or dialogs while executing in AuthMode.LIMITED. You can use menu items to open sidebars and dialogs since these run in AuthMode.FULL.

From  [Error "You do not have permission to call showSidebar" in onOpen and onEdit](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69238694) (an issue from the Google Apps Script issue tracker)

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior) Sorry for the delayed reply
> here. After many conversations with the engineering team it was
> decided that we cannot support opening UI elements (sidebars, dialogs)
> in onOpen and onEdit. The authorization lifecycle documentation has
> been updated to make it clear that you can only add menu items in
> those modes:
>
> https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/addon-authorization#authorization_modes
>
> We understand this impacts the possible user experiences you can
> provide and we apologize for the suddenness of the change.

Answer (score 0):

I retested, and I see that :

- on installing the Add-On, mode is set to FULL
- then opening a document mode is set to None
- on opening the add-on then, closing the document then reopens, mode is LIMITED.

That is consistent with the expected lifecycle, except that :

- createTemplate fails under LIMITED mode
- in LIMITED mode the event has {user=} with no value :

08:22:36.457 onOpen(): {authMode=LIMITED, source=Document, user=}

I think the user permissions are somewhat lost.